# With Xcode UI tests, is it possible to test application in external project/repository?

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am searching for a way to separate the UI tests from the original repository where the main app stays. Is it possible to have the UI test code in another repository, "reference" the main app in some way, and test it?

Answer (score 5):

Starting in Xcode 9, this is possible as long as you're willing to give up a few features. After creating a UI test bundle, you can go to the target settings to specify that it has no target application. (You may also be able to create a UI test bundle without specifying one to begin with.) After you've removed the target application, rather than using the default initializer for `XCUIApplication`, you can use the initializer that accepts a bundle identifier.

Your tests will end up looking something like the following:

```
var app: XCUIApplication {
    return XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.yourdomain.product")
}

func setup() {
    app.launch()
}

func test() {
    app.navigationBar.buttons["Add"].tap()
}
```

If you go this route, you will lose the ability to use a few features. Namely:

- You won't be able to use Xcode's built in test recorder. The record button is disabled unless you have a target application configured. That being said, you could create an empty app in your project and just switch to the application you'd like to record instead. (That being said, I haven't found Xcode's record feature to be very useful, even for single project apps.)
- Xcode won't automatically install your application for you. That usually isn't an issue since is located in a different repository (and sometimes isn't even an Xcode project), so you'll just need to install it before starting your tests. The iOS simulator allows you to drag and drop a .app file, so installing the app is easy enough.